# How to update with org.hibernate.Session?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have problem to get the methods update and merge and saveOrUpdate in org.hibernate.Session to work. The symptom is that the database just do not get updated, no exception is thrown.

```
@Override
public void update(Domain domain) {
    
    // Create a SessionFactory using the Hibernate utility method
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    // Obtain a session from the SessionFactory
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    
    //THIS IS FALSE
    boolean contains = session.contains((LogItem)domain);
    
    //session.update((LogItem)domain);
    //session.update( ((LogItem)domain).getClass().getName(), (LogItem)domain );
    //session.merge( (LogItem)domain );
    //session.merge( ((LogItem)domain).getClass().getName(), (LogItem)domain );
    //session.saveOrUpdate( (LogItem)domain );
    session.saveOrUpdate( ((LogItem)domain).getClass().getName(), (LogItem)domain );

    // Close the session
    session.close();
            
}
```

I just mention that save and read works just fine, looking like.

```
public Serializable create(Domain domain) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    
    // Create a SessionFactory using the Hibernate utility method
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    // Obtain a session from the SessionFactory
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    
    // Save the object to the database
    session.save(domain);

    // Close the session
    session.close();
    
    return domain;
}

public Domain read(long id) {
    
    // Create a SessionFactory using the Hibernate utility method
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    // Obtain a session from the SessionFactory
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    
    // Save the object to the database
    LogItem logItem = session.get( LogItem.class, id );


    // Close the session
    session.close();
    
    return logItem;
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/CRUDS_MySQL_Data_Source</property>
    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    
    <!-- Enable JTA integration -->
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">
      org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebLogicJtaPlatform
    </property> 
        
    <!-- Mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="com/mycompany/cruds/domain/LogItem.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My hibernate dependings look like:

```
[INFO] com.mycompany.cruds:app:ear:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.mycompany.cruds:server:ejb:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.23.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mycompany.cruds:interface:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mycompany.cruds:domain:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |        \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.mycompany.cruds:facade:war:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] \- com.mycompany.cruds:web-client:war:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
```

My HibernateUtil looks like:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

I also mention that if I use the EntityManager approach it works fine.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "your_persistence_unit_name")
private EntityManager em;

public void update(Domain domain) {
    
     em.merge(domain);

}
```

Could you help me to see what I have missed to get the update to work using org.hibernate.Session.

Best regards
Fredrik

---

EDIT 2023-02-18:
To show you the chain of calls I add these lines of code to the question.

This is the class with the hibernate code. The content is described above.

```
public class DomainHibernateDaoBean {
    
    public Serializable create(Domain domain) throws Exception { ... }

    public Domain read(long id) throws Exception { ... }
    
    public void update(Domain domain) throws Exception { ... }
}
```

This is the class that calls the methods in DomainHibernateDaoBean, remark the annotations.

```
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;

@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class CrudsTransactionSessionBean implements CrudSessionLocal {

    private DomainHibernateDaoBean domainHibernateDaoBean = new DomainHibernateDaoBean();       
    private boolean throwException;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    public CrudsTransactionSessionBean() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void update(Domain domain) throws Exception {
        try {
             domainHibernateDaoBean.update(domain);
          
            if (throwException) {
                throw new Exception("Mockup exception");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sessionContext.setRollbackOnly();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public Serializable create(Domain domain) throws Exception {
        try {
            Serializable serializableTemp = serializableTemp = domainHibernateDaoBean.create(domain);

            if (throwException) {
                throw new Exception("Mockup exception");
            }
            return serializableTemp;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sessionContext.setRollbackOnly();
            throw e; 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Domain read(long id) throws Exception {
        try {
            Domain searchResult = searchResult = domainHibernateDaoBean.read(id);
            if (throwException) {
                throw new Exception("Mockup exception");
            }
            return searchResult;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sessionContext.setRollbackOnly();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

I would say that CrudsTransactionSessionBean uses transactions provided from the container, right?

Those conatiner transactions are configured in persistence.xml, right?

My persistence.xml looks like this, remark that it uses classes and properties from hibernate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="your_persistence_unit_name" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/CRUDS_MySQL_Data_Source</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.mycompany.cruds.domain.LogItem</class>
        <class>com.mycompany.cruds.domain.Domain</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I tought that those transactions was the same transactions that I got from my HibernateUtil, but I am guess that I am wrong, right?

The thing that really make me think it was the same transaction was because if I set throwException = true and then call create(), what happens is that the insert in the database is rolled back. How is that possible if it is different transactions? Will the call if sessionContext.setRollbackOnly() also roll back transactions from HibernateUtil? If so how is that possible?

Best regards
Fredrik

Comment: You only open a session, no transaction. No transaction nothing will be persisted in the database.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this is whithin a container managed environment (with wls 14). The methods above is called from session beans marked with @TransactionAttribute(value=REQUIRED). Since the save() method works fine I think it is stranger that update() does not. I must have missed somerhing.

Comment: Which is a totally different transaction then the one you are using as you aren't using a container managed hibernate instance. The save is different as it will need to flush directly to obtain the primary key, the update does not. The fact that you are using a different hibernate then the one configured by yuour container (the entitymanager) shows also that it is a different session. Why are you loading it again in the firs tplace instead of using JPA? Why use plain hibernate over JPA here, there is no added benefit (only added complexity).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Really interesting. I bet you are right but I might still have some trouble understanding how it is different transactions. You see, if I throw an exception after the call to "create()", from the session bean, the transaction is rolled back. How is it possible that there are different transactions? I will edit the question with some more code/info so you see what I mean asap.

Comment: It is a different transaction because the container doesn't know anything about your hibernate setup, it only knows about your JPA setup. If you really want use JPA and use `unwrap` to get the underlying Hibernate `Session` from the `EntityManager`. You don't (nor should) open a new session yourself.

Comment: Hello M. Deinum, did you by any chance see my last edit? It would be Great to get your input about it. Best regards

Comment: Your edit doesn't change a thing. They are different transaction, no but just a period. Your JPA doesn't know about your Hibernate local setup, regardless if they share a datasource. They are different tx.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Do you by any chance see how I could use use hibernate.cfg.xml side by side with persistence.xml? (this is a try-out-app-only) Or perhaps it is better to create two apps?

Comment: You cannot as it will result in 2 different persistence instances which don't know anything about one another. Why would you want both? As I stated before if you really want to use the `Session` use `unwrap` on the `EntityManager`. Just configure one thing (JPA) and switch if you really need access to the `Session`. With the current state of JPA this is rarely needed.

Comment: Hello again, my conclusion is that in a CMT environment, one should not use code from hibernate like I did above. It really makes ni sense.

Comment: Which is what I tried to convey from the start :).